# Is there an equivalent of "isLonLat" function in terra package in R?

Tags: raster, sf, stars, terra

I am refactoring my code which extensively relied on `raster` package to now use the newer and better `terra` package. I was making use of the `isLonLat()` function that returns `TRUE` if the `crs` of a raster object is angular and `FALSE` if it's planar.

Is there a way to do this using `terra` instead?

I want to make my code future-proof and the reliance of this function on the now deprecated **proj4string** is not acceptable.

Comment: Have you looked as `sf::st_is_longlat`? It will take any CRS, say for terra or raster you could use `sf::st_is_longlat(sf::st_crs(terra::crs(x)))`

Comment: Do `?terra` and then "find" (Ctrl-F) on Windows and type `lonlat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your use case should be covered by [`sf::st_is_longlat()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/sf/man/st_is_longlat.html) function; it is primarily aimed at vector data, but since rasters (in both {terra} and {raster} flavors) have CRS methods it works for them too..

```
library(sf)
library(terra)

s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))

st_is_longlat(s)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This works. I don't mind adding `sf` in my list of dependencies since I will need the package further down in my script anyway. However, I feel `terra` developers should ensure this functionality is covered natively.

Comment: @FaustinGashakamba There is no need to ensure this functionality is covered natively because sf is already a "Suggests" dependency for terra and this can easily be facilitated using `sf::st_is_longlat(sf::st_crs(terra::crs(x)))`. In package development you want to avoid redundancy. The `sf::st_crs(terra::crs(x))` call parses the terra crs string to a formatted WKT that sf then recognizes. It even looks like in the recent release of terra, the string is automatically parsed to sf crs handling so, simply `st_crs(x)` and `is_longlat(x)`

Comment: @JeffreyEvans That's reassuring then. Anyway, I just found out I could also use `sf::st_crs(spatial_object)$IsGeographic` to ascertain whether the `crs` of an object is planar or angular. I am still a learner; so I you have to bear with me. Thanks.

Comment: @FaustinGashakamba I have found that the "named elements" that are associated with the WKT object are very inconsistent and depend on how the CRS is defined. So, you cannot always rely on name objects such as $IsGeographic, $epsg and $proj4string always being available. For code stability I would invoke a function to return this value.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have `terra::is.lonlat()` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/terra/versions/1.5-17/topics/is.lonlat